# Мой discord bot не видит коги

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord, discord-api

Недавно я решил рассортировать свой код и поделить на коги, но почему то когда я сделал выпадающее меню он перестал видеть мои команды и начал писать в консоль что команда не найдена.
Вот код main.py:

```
import discord
import sqlite3
import os
from config import settings
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=settings['prefix'], intents=intents)
bot.remove_command('help') 

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user} Готов пахать на благо общества!")

for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

bot.run(settings["token"])
```

Вот код shop.py который находится в папке cogs:

```
import discord
import sqlite3
import asyncio
from config import settings
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import Button, View, Select


conn = sqlite3.connect('Senton.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()  

class MenuShop(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        options = [
            discord.SelectOption(label="Эконома", description="Здания которые приносят постоянную прибыль", value="buttonEconomy", emoji="", ),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Производство", description="Здания которые производят ресурсы", value="buttonProduction", emoji="", ),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Военное", description="Снаряжения, техника, солдаты для военного положения", value="buttonWar", emoji="⚔", ),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Прочее", description="Прочие оборудование для развития страны", value="buttonNext", emoji="", )
        ]
        super().__init__(options=options)

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"You selected {self.values[0]}")



class commandsShop(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(aliases=['шоп', 'маг', 'магаз', 'маркет'])
    async def магазин(self, ctx):
        view1 = MenuShop()

        await ctx.reply(embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Магазин",
            description="Пожалуйста выберите раздел магазина.",
            color=0xFF0000
        ), view=view1)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(commandsShop(bot))
```